# Writing an equation as a telescopic series and finding its sum

Tags: calculus

[image]

So for this problem, the $\frac{1}{6}$ portion is correct. I did this through rewriting s using partial fractions, and getting $\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}$. Obviously, if we take the limit of this equation as n starts at 7 and goes to infinity, we get $\frac{1}{7-1} - 0$ = $\frac{1}{6}$. My question is how do you go about finding S sub capital N for this problem (The first question). Any kind of help on how to get started with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The very first example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) is germane.

Comment: They have not given any definition of $S_N$.

Comment: I thought I followed that procedure, first by adding up all of the first N terms then cancelling out the applicable numbers, leaving only $\frac{1}{6}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$. As a result, I'm left with $\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: I just got it. I don't stop at $\frac{1}{n}$ when I'm adding up the terms. Since n = 7 instead of n = 1, I needed to keep adding until I was up to $\frac{1}{N+6}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
S_N&=\sum_{n=7}^N\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=7}^N\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=7}^{N}\frac1{n-1}-\sum_{n=7}^{N}\frac1n\\\\
&=\sum_{n=6}^{N-1}\frac1n-\sum_{n=7}^{N}\frac1n\\\\
&=\frac16-\frac1N
\end{align}$$